# Why cannot get Text insert on JTEXTFIELD send to query mysql?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want get user text set on jtextfield and send to query to insert on database but I have a problem with return.

> Erro: ,Data truncation: Data too long for column 'nomecliente' at row 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL 
>   (total time: 7 seconds)

```
JTextField txtconta = new JTextField();
txtconta.getText();

try
{
    String query = "insert into clientes (idconta,nomecliente) values ('9999','"+txtconta+"');";
    this.statement.executeUpdate(query);
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.printf("Erro: ,"+ e.getMessage());
}

}
```

Comment: If the data is too long for the column, you need a bigger column (or shorter data). But you shouldn't be gluing variables directly into your query: you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate values into the SQL string. Learn to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I think this question should be closed since the error message is the answer to the question. What cause of action is needed to fix the issue is a too broad question depending on requirements, business logic etc.